# How to allow Firefox to save forms, but prohibit search bar saving

Tags: firefox, search, privacy

I wonder if there is a way to make Firefox to continue saving forms (like mail and nickname fields), but stop it from saving search history in the search field next to the address bar?

Comment: Your title isn't clever or particularly good. It's unclear and makes it difficult to be found.

Comment: As @DanielBeck said, your title wasn't very good. I've rolled back to a better version - **leave it be**.

Comment: In fact, i disagree: the title was both more clever, more compact, as well as **easier** to read compared to this one your are dictating. Sadly, the question behind it still remains.

Answer (score 4):

It seems Firefox doesn't support this behaviour despite several requests and questions. Consider the following:

[Feature Request](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/818786)

[Question](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/814844)